# How to box with div the propper way?

Tags: html, css

I am often using div to box in information but I have notice that the wrapping box might sometimes not fill out the space and this leads to elements from other wrappers entering the box area.

For example :

```
<div>
 <div style="length:150px;">my info1</div>
 <div style="length:50px;">my Info2</div>
</div>
```

Take a look at this example

```css
.topic {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
.topic .tInfo {
  float: left;
  width: 460px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.topic .tName {
  width: 460px;
  background-color: brown;
}
.topic .tTime {
  width: 460px;
  background-color: lime;
}
.topic .tUImgLnk {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}
.topic .tUImgLnk .tUImg {
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="topic" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0">
  <div class="tUImgLnk" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.0">
    <a title="Carl" target="_blank" href="http://www.bradspel.net" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.0.0">
      <img class="tUImg" src="" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.0.0.0">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="tInfo" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.1">
    <div class="tName" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.1.0"><a title="Carl" target="_blank" href="http://www.bradspel.net" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.1.0.0">Carl</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tTime" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.1.1"><span data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.1.1.0">2015-02-20 18:43:03</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="topic" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0">
  <div class="tUImgLnk" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.0">
    <a title="Carl" target="_blank" href="http://www.bradspel.net" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.0.0">
      <img class="tUImg" src="" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.0.0.0">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="tInfo" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.1">
    <div class="tName" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.1.0"><a title="Carl" target="_blank" href="http://www.bradspel.net" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.1.0.0">Carl</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tTime" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.1.1"><span data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.1.1.0">2015-02-20 18:43:03</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have used `<br style="clear:both"/>` at the end of each wrapper box but is this really the best way to go?

Comment: Give `overflow: hidden` to `.topic`

Comment: @anpsmn thanks, that works great, but why? Is this the best way? Or are clear:both still used?

Comment: You can use any one of them. The issue with `overflow:hidden` is it hides the overflow. [You can read more about it here](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happenning because you don't have a **wrapper** , and the elements are liberaly *floating*;

in the below snippet I wrapped your elements in rows with  `article` selector and cleared floats:

```css
.topic {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
.topic .tInfo {
  float: left;
  width: 460px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.topic .tName {
  width: 460px;
  background-color: brown;
}
.topic .tTime {
  width: 460px;
  background-color: lime;
}
.topic .tUImgLnk {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}
.topic .tUImgLnk .tUImg {
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  position: absolute;
}
article:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<article>
<div class="topic" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0">
  <div class="tUImgLnk" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.0">
    <a title="Carl" target="_blank" href="http://www.bradspel.net" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.0.0">
      <img class="tUImg" src="" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.0.0.0">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="tInfo" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.1">
    <div class="tName" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.1.0"><a title="Carl" target="_blank" href="http://www.bradspel.net" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.1.0.0">Carl</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tTime" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.1.1"><span data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.1.1.0">2015-02-20 18:43:03</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<article>
</article>
<div class="topic" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0">
  <div class="tUImgLnk" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.0">
    <a title="Carl" target="_blank" href="http://www.bradspel.net" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.0.0">
      <img class="tUImg" src="" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.0.0.0">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="tInfo" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.1">
    <div class="tName" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.1.0"><a title="Carl" target="_blank" href="http://www.bradspel.net" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.1.0.0">Carl</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tTime" data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.1.1"><span data-reactid=".24rl768raww.$0.1.1.0">2015-02-20 18:43:03</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</article>
```

Comment: this is the most popular-advanced way to clear floats AKA [clearfix-hack](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)